# SQL Server 2014 - Service Broker: maximum Services

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I am using SQL Server 2014 using FireDAC in Delphi XE7 to connect to the database.

We need an Event to automatically open a form if some Data where changed in a special Table. Therefor we found the **TFDEventAlerter** which we used to create a **Queue** and **Service** for each User.

```
UserEvent.Names.Add('QUEUE=qUserEvent');
UserEvent.Names.Add('SERVICE=s' + Username);
UserEvent.Names.Add('CHANGE1=usr;SELECT ID FROM dbo.MsgBox WHERE Status = 'A');
```

So we have got one Queue and a lot of Services that are listening to that Queue. In general this Setup ist working fine.

But if a lot of Users (550 in my case) are connecting to the database and adding new Services to the Queue we got the Problem that we are running into bad Performance enforced by *ThreadPool_Starvation* as each Service is blocking a Worker-Thread from time to time.

So does anybody know why there is a limitation using Services for the Service Broker in SQL Server 2014?

Is there another way to use the **TFDEventAlerter** with 500 Users without creating 500 Services? It seems to me, that we are not using the **TFDEventAlerter** as it is used to be.

Comment: If you are using three-tier access to the database via a datasnap server in the middle tier, then you don't need 500 FD event alerters.  You could have **one** event alerter in the datasnap server, and get it to invoke a callback method in the 500 clients.

Comment: Speaking from curiosity, but what does a "multiple service/one queue" architecture get you? Whenever I've implemented Service Broker, it's been 1:1.

Comment: @MartynA: Thank you for the idea. We will implement this solution if there realy is not other way to use the EventAlerter

Comment: @BenThul: You are right, normally we are using for each Service a separate Queue. So it´s 1:1, too. But for my tests it does not change anything. Our Problem ist the count of services, not the cout of Queues.

Comment: Could you perhaps use one service and one queue, but have a mapping between conversation handles and users? That is, when your application receives a message, it will know what user it's associated to because of what conversation handle is associated with the message. Alternatively, can you embed information that identifies the user right in the message itself?

Comment: @Maggi_MT:  Btw, although 3-tier is preferable to 2-tier from a security pov, especially over the internet, even if you want to stick with 2-tier for your db access, you could still have a minimal Datasnap server to do the callbacks I suggested.